# Пишет Встречено 'else', а ожидалось ';'

Tags: pascal

Пишет Встречено 'else', а ожидалось ';' я только учусь программированию. Можете описать как это исправить простым кодом

```
begin
var player := 1;
begin
var sum1 := 0;
var sum2 := 0;
var x : integer;
var (z,y) := random2(1,6);



  if player = 1 then
  repeat
  Println('Ваш ход');
  Println('Сколько раз встрясти стаканчик?:');
  sum1 += (z + y);
  until TryRead(x) and (x > 0) and (x <= 3);
  Print (sum1)
  else
  Println('Мой ход')
 
end.
```

Comment: Поправьте форматирование и сами все увидите, что else там ни к селу, ни к городу.

Comment: @Kromster а ";" в конце Print разве быть не должно?

Comment: @SwaD каша в коде (два `begin` еще зачем-то), скорее всего человек IF потерял, а как его вернет - так и `;` перед `else` не понадобится. А зачем вы меня об этом спрашиваете? ))

Comment: @Kromster Вспоминаю свои знания по pascal )) Да и думаю будет полезно тому, кто задал вопрос, вдруг пригодится

Comment: @SwaD begin я убрал, а дальше как?

Answer (score -1):

```pascal
program so1;
var
    player: integer = 1;
    sum1: integer = 0;
    sum2: integer = 0;
    x, y, z: integer;
begin
    y := 1 + random(7);
    z := 1 + random(7);
    if player = 1 then
    begin
        repeat
            writeln ('Ваш ход');
            writeln ('Сколько раз встрясти стаканчик?:');
            read(x);
            sum1 += (z + y);
        until (x > 0) and (x <= 3);
        write (sum1);
    end
    else
    begin
        writeln ('Мой ход');
    end;
end.
```